# Requesting item from Factory without hard-coding every case

Tags: java, class, interface, factory, hardcode

I have an interface called Command:

```
public interface Command {
// irrelevant code
}
```

And about 15 classes that implement this interface:

```
public class Comm_A implements Command {
// irrelevant code
}

public class Comm_B implements Command {...}
....
public class Comm_XZ implements Command {...}
```

And the factory which should take a String and return an instance of the corresponding command:

```
public class CommandFactory {
    public static Command getCommand(String s) {
        if (s.equals("Comm_A")) return new Comm_A();
        else ... // each particular case
    }
}
```

Consider that I want to be able to add new Commands without changing the factory code.

Can I make it to automatically try and create the corresponding instance WITHOUT hard-coding each "Comm_A"..."Comm_XZ" case and WITHOUT using java.lang.reflect?

Comment: Can you call 'getCommand()' with a class instead of a String?

Comment: No, the string is read from a JTextPane and manually entered.

Comment: Why don't you want to use reflect? While I agree that it is usually wise to stay away of it while you do not need it (and avoid "clever" tricks), this use case is perfect for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate the fully qualified name (package.class) and call

`Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(className);`

Then call

```
myClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: He asked without reflection.

Comment: I was curious if there is any other way except reflection, but if not I can use that. Thank you!

Comment: Class.forName is not part of java.lang.reflect.

Comment: Any other way will get you the same result, only now you'll have a parallel "reflection" module that was less debugged than Class.forName

Answer (score 1):

If your commands are stateless, thread-safe objects, you can create a map of eagerly-created instances and use these instances repeatedly:

```
public class CommandFactory {
    private final Map<String, Command> availableCommands;

    public CommandFactory(Map<String, Command> availableCommands) {
        this.availableCommands = availableCommands;
    }

    public Command getCommand(String s) {
        if (availableCommands.contains(s) {
            return availableCommands.get(s);
        } else {
            // handle error state
        }
    }
}
```

For this to be any good (and fulfill the "no changes to the class" requirement) however the factory would *not* be a static class, with instance (rather than static) `getCommand()` method. The available commands then can be injected using a DI framework.

---

If you need to create a new instance of the `Command` implementation for each call, then you cannot really avoid reflection without using the terrible `if...else if` chain. I wouldn't be too worried about using it in this case though, `Class.newInstance()` is quite readable and not terribly inefficient.

I would still stick with that map approach though even for this, to make it flexible and extendable by configuration. The code would be similar just with `Map<String, Class>`, `return availableCommands.get(s).newInstance()` and some more exception checking.

---

A third possible approach is creating a separate factory class for each command type, and having a `Map<String, SpecificCommandFactory>`, where you'd query for the appropriate factory and then use that factory to get a new instance of that specific command class - but this is a lot of boilerplate code and can be quite unreadable, so is only suitable if you really need to separate the commands available from the factory:

```
public iterface SpecificCommandFactory {
    Command createCommand();
}

public class Comm_AFactory implements SpecificCommandFactory {
    public Comm_A createCommand() {
        return new Comm_A();
    }
}

public class CommandFactory {
    private final Map<String, SpecificCommandFactory> availableCommands;

    public CommandFactory(Map<String, Command> availableCommands) {
        this.availableCommands = availableCommands;
    }

    public Command getCommand(String s) {
        if (availableCommands.contains(s) {
            return availableCommands.get(s).createCommand();
        } else {
            // handle error state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would give you one object per class type, instead of a new object each time.

Comment: You could also have `Map<String, Class>` to construct a new object each time

Comment: Yeah, but if you do that, then how are you better than `Class.forName`?

Comment: @Shloim yes, that's true, it can only be used if that's not a problem - which is why I wrote "If your commands are stateless, thread-safe objects..."

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of delegating factory for this. Instead of holding references to the objects in a map (as in Jiri Tousek's answer) you could hold factories for the different commands:

```
public class CommandFactory{
    private static final Map<String, Callable<Command>> commands = new HashMap<>();
    public static void registerCommand(String command, Callable<Command> factory){
        commands.put(command, factory);
    }
    public static Command getCommand(String command){
        Callable<Command> factory = commands.get(command);
        if(factory != null){
            return factory.call();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```